# Unable to configure Tomcat 7 on Eclipse Juno

Tags: linux, eclipse, tomcat

I have Eclipse Juno with Spring Tools Suite plugin installed.

I need to deploy a newly imported web project to Tomcat 7, which I installed on my system via repository.

The problem is that the `New Server Wizard` screen won't allow me to select Tomcat 7, as the description is empty and unmodifiable.

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

How can I fix this? I can select other versions of Tomcat but when I select the installation path of Tomcat I get an error that the installed version is 7.

Comment: maybe not related to your question, do you feel juno extremely slow?   I did, and switched to v3.8, faster, but still slow... much slower than 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the instruction s provided in this [site](http://hariprasad.info/cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-type-eclipse-tomcat/)

Follow these steps, as this is a known issue

1. Go to `Window–>Preferences–>Server–>Runtime Environments` and fix the broken path/link for the server.
2. Rename the `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs` to `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs.bak` (or you can delete this file). This file can be found at `\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings`
3. Rename the `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs` to `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs.bak` (or delete the file).  This file also can be found at the same location as above.

Comment: That worked. But unfortunately I now get an error about configuration being corrupt. Tomcat is up and path is "/usr/share/tomcat" perhaps I'll open another question

Answer (score 1):

```
Follow these steps

1.)Go to Window–>Preferences–>Server–>Runtime Environments and fix the broken path/link for the server.
2.)delete this file org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs under this location \workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings
3.)delete this file org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs under this location \workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings

After following these step's you can configure tomcat in eclipse.
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Try going to New Server Wizard]

Click on Add Configuration Runtime environments

[image]

On the Server Runtime Environments Window you will more than likely see Apache Tomcat 7.
If you remove the runtime environment and then go Back to the New Server Wizard Tomcat 7 will be available to add again.

Hope that helps. That drove me nuts for a few days

Answer (score -1):

The Eclipse Juno may not be fully compatible with the Apache Tomcat 7 yet.  Installing and configuring with Tomcat 6 works.  Simple.